# Free, simple 3d modelling tool for jewelry design

Tags: gratis, windows-7, modeling

I am looking for a simple 3D modelling tool to design jewelry.

- Simple to use.  I don't plan on doing this very often, trying to design something for an anniversary.
- Free...same as above.
- 3D modelling
- Accurate dimensions
- Layering display (for lack of a better explanation think of a Celtic knot where lines overlap

I am unfamiliar with modelling software but google searching led me to a bunch of very expensive jewelry software.  If there are other aspects I need to consider let me know.

Comment: Look here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3530/2401

Answer (score 4):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org) is a free and open-source 3D modeling tool. I'm not sure if you would call Blender "simple," but it's certainly a capable option worth exploring. Due to its popularity, there should be many learning resources available online.

In fact, a quick search yielded a [tutorial about jewelry design in Blender](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/01/04/tutorial-designing-jewelry-for-3d-printing-with-blender/), which may be useful to you!

Answer (score 3):

[SketchUp](http://www.sketchup.com/)(Free, Easy to Learn, Easy to use) is a great choice for such tasks.

Though SketchUp is mostly used for architectural and interior designs, it's certainly capable of modeling complex objects such as jewelry.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsHRGDvN4sM) is a Tutorial that will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Decoded Heart](http://www.decodedheart.com) could help. It's as simple as it gets. 
This tool is aimed to people without ANY experience in 3D modeling.
You have limited possibilities, but I believe you can still get very creative. 
If you want to design charms with your own picture or text, it's a way to go

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed. How does it meet the requirements? What about costs? Are you [associated with this software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) in any way?

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing "Layering display" in action, thanks!